# Какой вариант предложения правильный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Как думаешь встретятся ли души умерших после смерти, которые любили друг друга"

"Как ты думаешь встретятся ли после смерти души умерших, которые любили друг друга"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба предложения некорректны.

1. После *как думаешь* и после *как ты думаешь* требуется запятая.
2. "Души умерших после смерти" — тавтологичная фраза, одно из слов (*умерших* или *после смерти*) необходимо убрать.
3. Местоимение *которые* присоединяет придаточное и указывает на тот предмет, о котором говорится в главном предложении, — *души*.
   Обычно эти слова стоят рядом, чтобы не возникало двусмысленности. А она из-за их "оторванности" в Вашем предложении присутствует: "после смерти, которая".
4. Не души любили друг друга, а люди, которым эти души когда-то "принадлежали". Нужно пояснить.
5. Интонация в предложении вопросительная (как мне кажется) — требуется знак вопроса.

Как думаешь, встретятся ли после смерти души тех (людей), которые любили друг друга?
Как ты думаешь, встретятся ли после смерти души тех, кто любил друг друга?

Answer (score 0):

Оба плохи. Я бы предложил такой вариант:

**Как ты думаешь, встретятся ли после смерти души тех людей, которые любили друг друга?**

"Как ты думаешь" — главное предложение в СПП, поэтому необходимо последующую часть отделить запятой. Союзное слово "который" желательно расположить ближе к существительному, к которому оно относится. Выбор слова "умерших" в качестве этого существительного не выглядит удачным, поскольку слово "любить" с ним сочетается не лучшим образом. Ну и вопросительный знак в конце вопросительного предложения обязателен, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант допускается, если автор собирается использовать [солецизм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) ([анаколуф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%84)).

Второй вариант, хотя и кажется требующим уточнения, на самом деле его не требует: любовь - дело живых, а в посмертии обычно не до любви :-)

Наличие или отсутствие местоимения "ты" зависит от степени социальной дистанции между говорящим и собеседником (при более близкой дистанции местоимение пропускается).

И - да, в каждом случае необходима запятая после "думаешь".

Comment: Дополню, что это вопросительное предложение.

Comment: Солецизм - разновидность грамматической _ошибки_, а не стилистический приём, - зачем автору его "использовать"?

Comment: @Alex_ander Зачем - это вопрос к автору. А если Вы внимательно прочтёте статьи по ссылкам, то станет понятно, что это - именно с.т.и.л.и.с.т.и.ч.е.с.к.и.й. п.р.и.ё.м., а не "ошибка".

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказала так:

*Как ты думаешь, встретятся после смерти души людей, которые любили друг друга?*

Здесь соблюдена необходимая информативность, а также выдержан разговорный стиль дружеской беседы.

Поэтому лучше оставить местоимение *ты*, а частицу-союз *ли* убрать (она характерна для книжной речи). Другой вариант:  можно считать первое предложение вводным.

Answer (score 0):

Возможен только *второй* вариант (если добавить пропущенную запятую после "думаешь"): в первом варианте союзное слово "которые" недопустимым образом оторвано от "умерших". Если дополнительно побороться за стиль, можно так:

> Как ты думаешь, встречаются ли после смерти души любивших друг друга
>   людей?